# why could not parse the kubernetes internal dns name

Tags: kubernetes, dns

when I run my python3 application in kubernetes cluster 1.28.3, shows error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/visa/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "/root/visa/task/refresh_token.py", line 17, in do_access_token_refresh
    accounts = vb.get_new_cf_user()
  File "/root/visa/config/mysql_utils.py", line 106, in get_new_cf_user
    return self.formatter_account_list(self.conn.query_db(sql, (cur_time, cur_time - 60 * 1000)))
  File "/root/visa/config/mysql_utils.py", line 368, in query_db
    conn = self.pool.connection()
  File "/root/visa/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbutils/pooled_db.py", line 330, in connection
    con = self.steady_connection()
  File "/root/visa/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbutils/pooled_db.py", line 281, in steady_connection
    return connect(
  File "/root/visa/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbutils/steady_db.py", line 131, in connect
    return SteadyDBConnection(
  File "/root/visa/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbutils/steady_db.py", line 190, in __init__
    self._store(self._create())
  File "/root/visa/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbutils/steady_db.py", line 208, in _create
    con = self._creator(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/visa/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 352, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/root/visa/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 668, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on "\'apollo-mysql-0.apollo-mysql.reddwarf-storage.svc.cluster.local\'" ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)')
```

I use the ping in the kubernetes pod and found it works:

```
root@visa-service-5675dccd5-l686n:~/visa# ping apollo-mysql-0.apollo-mysql.reddwarf-storage.svc.cluster.local
PING apollo-mysql-0.apollo-mysql.reddwarf-storage.svc.cluster.local (10.0.0.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10-0-0-238.apollo-mysql-headless.reddwarf-storage.svc.cluster.local (10.0.0.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.63 ms
64 bytes from 10-0-0-238.apollo-mysql-headless.reddwarf-storage.svc.cluster.local (10.0.0.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.52 ms
64 bytes from 10-0-0-238.apollo-mysql-headless.reddwarf-storage.svc.cluster.local (10.0.0.238): icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=1.53 ms
64 bytes from 10-0-0-238.apollo-mysql-headless.reddwarf-storage.svc.cluster.local (10.0.0.238): icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=1.54 ms
```

why the application could not parse the kubernetes cluster internal dns domain? Am I misssing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? this is the startup command:

```
pdm run python3.10 main_api.py
```

I can make sure this mysql address are working correct because I already have another service using the mysql.